# Empty review queue showing "1 Proposed Change"

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, review-queues, documentation-proposals

As a image says more than 42 words:

> [image]

It appears there are secret changes being suggested ;-)

When there *are* proposed changes, the count is also incorrect:

> [image]

Comment: Related: when there _are_ reviews available, the count is also 1 too high.

Comment: +1 for the hand-drawn circle. +1 for noticing that. -1 for being mean by posting this one hour before I was going to post this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a bug where it was possible for a topic draft not to get marked as reviewed if it was deleting a topic, but the topic was already deleted by the time the proposed change with that draft was reviewed.

I fixed up the affected draft in the DB and pushed a fix to prevent this from happening again in the future.